# Как занести в БД данные?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, phpmyadmin, mysqli

Вот как выглядит магазин-корзина
[image]

Вот код корзины в html

```
</head>
<body ng-app="shoppingcart" ng-controller="shoppingCTR">
    <section>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
     
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div id = "bg-background" class="col-8">
            <h4>PRODUCTS<h4>
            <hr style = "border-top:1px groovy #ccc;">
            <div id = "product">
                <div id = "p_list" ng-repeat = "product in products ">
                    <span style="font-size:16px;">{{product.p_name}}</span>
                    <center><img ng-src = "{{product.p_image}}"/></center>
                    <div><label style="font-size:14px;">Price:{{product.p_price}}  грн</label></div>
                    <center><button type = "button" class="btn1 btn-primary" ng-click = "add_cart(product)"> Add to cart</button></center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class = "panel panel-primary">
                <div class = "panel-heading">
                    <h5>MY CART</h5>
                </div>
                <div class = "panel-body table-responsive">
                    <table class = "table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Product</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat = "cart in carts" ng-init = "setTotals(cart)">
                                <td>{{cart.p_name}}</td>
                                <td>{{cart.p_price}} грн</td>
                                <td><button type = "button" ng-click = "remove_cart(cart)" class = "btn btn-danger"> X</button></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align = "right">Total</td>
                                <td>{{total}} грн</td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                      <?= Html::submitButton('Send', ['class'=>'btn btn-success' ])?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

а это к ней часть джавы

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("shoppingcart", [])
.controller("shoppingCTR", function($scope){
    $scope.carts=[];
    $scope.products = [
        {p_id: "1", p_name: "Тигролови", p_image: "/frontend/images/book1.png", p_price: 90 },
        {p_id: "2", p_name: "Агата Крісті", p_image: "/frontend/images/book2.png", p_price: 150},
        {p_id: "3", p_name: "Лісова пісня", p_image: "/frontend/images/book3.png", p_price: 120},
    ];
                 
    $scope.add_cart = function(product){
        if(product){
            $scope.carts.push({p_id: product.p_id, p_name: product.p_name, p_price: product.p_price});
        }   
    }
                         
    $scope.total = 0;
                 
    $scope.setTotals = function(cart){
        if(cart){
            $scope.total += cart.p_price;
        }
    }
                 
    $scope.remove_cart = function(cart){
        if(cart){
            $scope.carts.splice($scope.carts.indexOf(cart), 1);
            $scope.total -= cart.p_price;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Вопрос, как сделать так , что бы заказы, которые выводятся в My Cart записывались в базу данных и желательно с именем пользователя , который его осуществил

Comment: Подозреваю что нужно написать код который примет данные и сохранит их в БД, желательно сделать так чтобы код принимал идентификатор пользователя и сохранял его тоже.

Comment: "к ней часть джавы" -- это НЕ джава

Comment: В целом вопрос слииишком общий

Comment: AJAX и один скрипт на php, это если очень быстро и на коленке

Comment: Если коротко, тут есть пример, как в yii2 делать CRUD-контроллер, он вам понадобится для добавления/удаления элементов корзины https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/start-gii . После этого из методов add_cart и remove_cart  надо отправлять соответствующие ajax-запросы к контроллеру для изменения данных в БД, для этого можете использовать fetch https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch